# why whitespace not allowed between two keywords/constants written in xtext file for DSL

Tags: dsl, xtext

White space between `if` and `(` is not allowed.  For example, this works `IF(` but `IF (` causes a parser error.

The Rule is:

```
Condition returns ResultExpression:
   'IF' '(' condition=BooleanExpression ')' '{' then=ResultExpressionRhs '}' 
   (=> 'ELSE' '{' else=ResultExpression '}')?;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on from just this minimal grammar snippet.

Please check your xtext file for the following things:

1. A proper hidden clause that includes the WS
2. A keyword 'IF(' that may have been introduced by accident
3. Warnings when executing the workflow.